# DocuSign specify whether to open the DocuSign Add Fields view or the Prepare view when getting signatures

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi, microsoft-dynamics, docusign-sdk

I am having trouble figuring out how to specify whether to open the DocuSign Add Fields view or the Prepare view when getting signatures through the DocuSign C# SDK.

The reason is: We have been using the [DocuSign for Dynamics](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dynamics-365/docusign.3701c77e-1cfa-4c56-91e6-3ed0b622145a?tab=overview) App provided by Microsoft to send DocuSign envelopes from Dynamics CRM, but now we are working on implementing this as a custom server-side logic.

Now this app provides some workflows to integrate DocuSign into CRM, and I have found the documentation for it, that explains each step.

[image]

Here, since I have no way of reverse-engineering the actual logic that this runs, I am guessing the `One Click Send` parameter refers to the `Status` parameter of the envelope, since it determines whether the envelope is sent automatically or not.

I am not sure about the `One Click Options` parameter.

We would like to send the envelope automatically, so the `Status` parameter should probably be set to `"Sent"`, but how do I specify whether to open the DocuSign Add Fields view or the Prepare view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the One Click Options give you the option to open the sender view (embedded sending). The sender view enables you to edit the tabs, documents, recipients and other settings of draft DocuSign envelopes within your app before sending them out. You can get this sender view URL through the createSenderView API: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createsender/

While calling this API you can specify which page to open at first by "send" query parameter. If you set it as 1, then the sender view starts the signer in the tagging screen. If you set it as 0, the sender view starts the signer in the prepare screen.

More information about embedded sending is here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/